# Dedekind ring characterization via projective modules

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I am looking for a book or course notes proving the following result:

> Let $R$ be an integral domain. Then $R$ is a Dedekind ring if and only if every submodule of a projective $R$-module is projective.

This does not seem to be as easy to find as some of the other equivalent definitions of a Dedekind ring. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Milnor's book on K-theory, Princeton University Press

Comment: [These notes](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~edix/tag_2009/michiel_3.pdf) seem brief and to the point.

Comment: I don't see where this is in the link. It looks like one direction follows from the structure theorem near the end, but I don't see the converse

Answer (score 5):

"$\Leftarrow$" $R$ is a projective $R$-module, and therefore all ideals of $R$ are projective, that is, invertible. [This](http://planetmath.org/proofthatadomainisdedekindifitsidealsareinvertible) implies that $R$ is Dedekind.

"$\Rightarrow$" Since $R$ is Dedekind every ideal of $R$ is projective which is the definition (or one of them) of *hereditary* rings. Now we have to show that this property is equivalent the fact that any submodule of a projective module is projective. But this is well-known and follows easily from [Kaplansky's Theorem](http://books.google.ro/books?id=X5MlYiyUb_YC&pg=PA135&lpg=PA135&dq=theorem+5.5.1+kaplansky&source=bl&ots=9aJiRwpey6&sig=O4Hiog_1XOtAsaVyySX1Xl4V4Wo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TKSpUvCJEcTOswaJmIDACw&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=theorem%205.5.1%20kaplansky&f=false).